# Identify important less frequent words

Tags: data-mining, nlp, text-mining

I have set of newspaper articles. I want to identify important less frequent words in the set of newspaper articles. Currently I am using TF-IDF scores. However, it does not seem to be a good metric in my problem. Is there any better way of doing this?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Describe the problem. Non-stationarity? Neologisms?

Comment: @Emre This is a classification of newspaper atricles based on topics. For example `sports`, `crime` etc. Iwant to identify the important words to do this.

Comment: You want to _classify_ or tag the article by topic? If so, you want a [document classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_classification) or [topic model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model) depending on whether the topics are fixed or not. How did you classifiy using the TF-IDF features and how well did it perform? I suppose you tried a bunch of classifiers and did not like the results? Try augmenting the features with the document's topic embedding.

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking just at the IDF scores. Things like names/entities will score high, this may be desirable or undesirable depending on what you want.